Django REST 404 sending params in the url
Good day, I'm having problems with django/ django rest apí
Back:
url(r'^' + baseurl + etl + eph + 'salud_folder_xls/listar/<str:accion>/', etlEPHSaludXLSListar),
   
url(r'^' + baseurl + etl + eph + 'salud_folder_xls/descargar/(?P<nombre_archivo>.+\\.xls)', etlEPHDescargarSaludFolderXLS),

Front:
    const response = await axios({
    url: '/etl/v1/eph/salud_folder_xls/listar/',
    method: 'GET',
  });

Case 1 :
const response = await axios({ url: '/etl/v1/eph/salud_folder_xls/listar', method: 'GET', }); 

salud_folder_xls/listar/

output >> Return 200
Case 2 :
const response = await axios({ url: '/etl/v1/eph/salud_folder_xls/listar/perro/', method: 'GET', }); 

salud_folder_xls/listar/<str:accion>/' 

output >> doesnt work (return a 404)

What do you mean by When I try salud_folder_xls/listar/ works fine? Oh, you mean that the apex path works well but not if you add accion to it? Is that URL available on your backend? Might not be an issue with the front-end side. Give it a try with Postman, you should have the same error.

Case 1 :  const response = await axios({
url: '/etl/v1/eph/salud_folder_xls/listar',
method: 'GET',
}); and salud_folder_xls/listar/ => Return 200 and works fine  //// Case 2 :  const response = await axios({
url: '/etl/v1/eph/salud_folder_xls/listar/perro/',
method: 'GET',
}); and salud_folder_xls/listar/str:accion/' doesnt work (return a 404)

Please edit your question with that rather than writing it into a comment. Also, my Postman states still stands.
